# How to change searchBar width programmatically? (Swift)

Tags: swift, width, searchbar

I'd like to resize my app components when device is turned into left or right side - when it keep horizontal position

I'm checking device rotation in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` event and then I have to change width of searchBar and tableView. How should I do it? I tried some variants with components `.frame` and with `CGRect`, nothing works.
[image]

**Update**:
it can be done without any code. View my answer below

Comment: Are you trying to keep a consistent space on either side of the search bar?
Auto-layout would probably be the best use here.
More info on your setup would be helpful.
Are you using storyboards? Do you have size classes turned on?

Comment: I'm using standard main.storyboard, no one size classes. I'd like to set searchBar width in maximal value when device turns horizontal only

Comment: If you're using storyboard, enable Auto layout.
Create constraints on your searchBar, pinning it to it's container (or closest neighbor) on left, right, and top.
When you rotate the device, it should stretch to fill the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you laid out your elements in Interface Builder then you can just add an outlet to the width constraint of your search bar. Then, change the constraint's `constant` property to change the bar's width.

Comment: Can you please help with code example of your advice? You know, my nickname speaks for itself)

Comment: Your answer below is correctly the method I was trying to explain. There's little\no code involved, as everything is done in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do I need
So, the task is that components will be resized in width when device turns horizontally.

1) Select items must be resized

2) Select "**Leading Space to SuperView**"

[image]

3) Without unselection, select "**Add missing Constraints**"

[image]

That's it. Now they will be resized correctly